# Maven can't retrieve buildNumber while package the jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I am using a buildnumber-maven-plugin to generate a sequence number for my jar. I will use it during my CICD process.

I followed all the examples available online. However, I can get the ${buildNumber} to print it, but while packaging the jar, I can't get the number, and I got the ${buildNumber} text. I searched for Maven LifeCycle, and I found I need to add it in the validation before any other plugin. But still, I can't solve the issue.

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>${group.id}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${artifact.id}</artifactId>
    <version>${model.version}</version>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>scala-2.11</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>

        ......
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://127.0.0.1/dummy</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://127.0.0.1/dummy</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
        <url>http://127.0.0.1/dummy</url>
    </scm>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <finalName>${artifact.id}.${model.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- buildnumber-maven-plugin for automatic increment the version number -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <buildNumberPropertiesFileLocation>${build.number.dir}</buildNumberPropertiesFileLocation>
                    <revisionOnScmFailure>no.scm.config.in.pom</revisionOnScmFailure>
                    <doCheck>true</doCheck>
                    <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
                    <format>{0,number}</format>
                    <items>
                        <item>buildNumber</item>
                    </items>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>${build.number.dir}</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo>current build number is "${buildNumber}"</echo>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- ================== ;-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.source.version}</target>
                    <skipMain>true</skipMain> <!-- skip compile -->
                    <skip>true</skip> <!-- skip testCompile -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.assembly.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>
                                    src/main/assembly/assembly-jar.xml
                                </descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                            <finalName>${artifact.id}</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bin</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>
                                    src/main/assembly/assembly-bin.xml
                                </descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                            <finalName>${tar.name}</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>



    <properties>
        <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dlog4j.skipJansi=false -DmodelLogLevel=${modelLogLevel}</argLine>
        <modelLogLevel>DEBUG</modelLogLevel>
            <build.number.dir>${project.basedir}/buildNumber.properties</build.number.dir>
        <java.source.version>1.8</java.source.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>


        <!-- Plugin Versions -->
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.6.2</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <maven.reports.plugin.version>2.9</maven.reports.plugin.version>
        <maven.assembly.plugin.version>3.1.0</maven.assembly.plugin.version>
        <surefire.plugin.version>2.7</surefire.plugin.version>

        <group.id>com.test.model_name</group.id>
        <artifact.id>proj_abc</artifact.id>
        <build.type>snapshot</build.type>
        <major.minor.version>0.1</major.minor.version>
            <!-- here I am trying to retrieve the actual number-->
        <build.number>${buildNumber}</build.number>
        <model.version>${major.minor.version}.${build.number}.${build.type}</model.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Note: If I run validate I could found the echo message below which means I can get the number correctly from the properties file. If I run package or run I got ${artifact.id}_source-.0.1.${buildNumber}.snapshot without the number.

```
main:
     [echo] current build number is "90"
```

I also checked this similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978918/include-package-in-maven-while-preparing-jar) & [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981120/buildnumber-not-generated-with-buildnumber-maven-plugin) and other links but can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Where is `${artifact.id}_source-.0.1.${buildNumber}.snapshot` being used? I don't see it in the POM. - Never mind, I see... it's the `model.version` property.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening here is that Maven resolves properties near the beginning of the build process.

```
<build.number>${buildNumber}</build.number>
<model.version>${major.minor.version}.${build.number}.${build.type}</model.version>
```

When it resolves `build.number`, `${buildNumber}` does not have a value. So, it leaves the variable name unchanged. And I suspect you'd have the same problem if you modified `model.version` to this:

```
<model.version>${major.minor.version}.${buildNumber}.${build.type}</model.version>
```

for the same reason.

You can try using the `build-helper-maven-plugin` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12002359/944849). However, this still may not work since `model.version` is used as the value of the `project.version`, which is resolved quite early as it's part of the GAV coordinates. It's worth a try though.